# Tomcat y .WAR cómo insertar un botón para imprimir ticket en un restaurante y para trabajar con productos con 3 precios en el programa UNICENTAOPOS

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Estoy trabajando con un programa llamando UnicentaOpos que está diseñado en Java, tengo que conectar a la base de datos a través de un iPod a tomar la orden y enviar la comanda a la cocina. Puedo conectar a la base de datos a través de esta aplicación ( https://sourceforge.net/p/nordpos/discussion/restaurant-service/thread/9446cfc9/ ) instalado en un servidor Tomcat y funciona de manera perfecta siempre que el producto tenga un sólo precio ya que puede tener 3 precios diferentes (bar, salón, terraza). Originalmente el programa (UnicentaPos) solo trabaja con un precio por producto pero alguien modificó eso y compartió la solución que es modificar el programa y la base de datos para que pueda trabajar con 3 precios... Aquí viene el problema y es que el .WAR esta hecho para que funcione con un precio por producto peta al intentar utilizarlo cuando se modifica la base de datos. Necesito dos cosas:

1. Modificar el WAR para que funcione sin ningún problema con productos con 3 precios.
2. Cómo mandar a imprimir la comanda desde el .WAR?

[image: todo correcto cuando la base de datos NO esta modificada]

Como pueden observar en la segunda imagen, se pueden agregar los productos que estan en la base de datos sin ningun problema. Lo que necesito es mandar a imprimir esos productos a la impresora que esta en la cocina.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    uniCenta oPOS - Touch friendly Point Of Sale
    Copyright (c) 2009-2012 uniCenta.
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/unicentaopos

    This file is part of uniCenta oPOS.

    uniCenta oPOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    uniCenta oPOS is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with uniCenta oPOS.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
-->

<output>

    <display>
        <line>
            <text align="left" length="10">Order sent to Kitchen</text>
            <text align="right" length="10">${ticket.printTotal()}</text>
        </line>
        <line>
            <text align="center" length="20">Thank you.</text>
        </line>
    </display>

    <ticket printer = "2">
        <line></line>
        <line></line>
        <line size = "1">
            <text bold = "true" align="center" length="42">Kitchen Order</text>
        </line>
        <line></line>
        <line>
            <text align="left" length="15">Receipt:</text>
            <text>${ticket.printId()}</text>
        </line>
        <line>
            <text align="left" length="15">Date:</text>
            <text>${ticket.printDate()}</text>
        </line>

    #if ($ticket.getCustomer())
        <line>
            <text align="left" length="15">Customer:</text>
            <text>${ticket.getCustomer().getName()}</text>
        </line>
        <line>
            <text align="left" length="15"></text>
            <text align="left" length="15">Account #:</text>
            <text>${ticket.getCustomer().getTaxid()}</text>
        </line>
    #end


        #if (${tickettext.place} != ${place})
        <line>
           <text align="left" length="15">Table:</text>
           <text>${place}</text>
        </line>
        #end
        
        <line></line>
        <line>
            <text align ="left" length="17">Item</text>
            <text align ="right" length="5"></text>
        </line>
        <line>
            <text>------------------------------------------</text>
        </line>
    #foreach ($ticketline in $ticket.getLines())
        #if(($ticketline.isProductKitchen()) && ($ticketline.getProperty("sendstatus").equals("No")))
            <line size = "1">
                <text align ="left" length="5">${ticketline.printMultiply()}x</text>
                #if ($ticketline.isProductCom())
                    <text align ="left" length="37">--${ticketline.printName()}</text>
                #else
                    <text align ="left" length="37">${ticketline.printName()}</text>
                #end
            </line>
            <!-- Add the following lines only for 2.30 Attributes -->
              #if ($ticketline.productAttSetInstId)
                <line>
                    <text align ="left" length="42">    ${ticketline.productAttSetInstDesc}</text>
                </line>
                <line></line>
            #end
         #end

    #end
        <line>
            <text>------------------------------------------</text>
        </line>
        <line>
            <text align="left" length="15">Server:</text>
            <text>${ticket.printUser()}</text>
        </line>
    </ticket>
</output>
```

Éste es el código que se ejecuta en la aplicación del ordenador, prácticamente lo que necesito es que eso mismo que realize en el .WAR

PD: UnicentaOpos esta basado en Java.

Comment: publica todos los enlaces del software y el método de instalación y configuración completo que estas usando para poderlo replicar en una vm y ver el problema con más detalles (servidor tomcat, archivos war, unicenta (version), si es con wamp o todo por separado, etc)